# Javafx: How to transform a Rectangle keeping it in the center?

Tags: java, events, shapes

I have to create a "slot machine effect": I have a root layer an on it I have 3 `Rectangle`s, each one in a `TilePane` cell. i tryed to add an event handler that should modify the rect (resizing it and rotating it) in order to change the figure that it displays. Unfortunately, my figure is never at the center fo its cell. How can I fix it?

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author bog
 */
public class Test extends Application {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    TilePane tp = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //root.getChildren().add(btn);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
            final Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.GREY);
            r.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int n = rnd.nextInt(5);
                    if(n == 0){     // horizontal line
                        r.setWidth(100);
                        r.setHeight(5);
                        System.out.println("Linea orizontale");
                    }
                    if(n == 1){     // vertical line
                        r.setWidth(5);
                        r.setHeight(100);
                        System.out.println("Linea verticale");
                    }
                    if(n == 2){     // rombo
                        r.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45,50,50));
                        System.out.println("rombo");
                    }
                    if(n == 3){     // back-slash line
                        r.setWidth(5);
                        r.setHeight(100);
                        r.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45,50,50));
                        System.out.println("Linea /");
                    }
                    if(n == 4){     // slash line
                        r.setWidth(100);
                        r.setHeight(5);
                        r.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45,50,50));
                        System.out.println("Linea \\");
                    }
                }
            });
            final StackPane sp = new StackPane();
            sp.getChildren().add(r);
            tp.getChildren().add(sp);
        }
        tp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(tp);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 450);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not quite sure what is your problem , and right now i cant test your code , but almost every time i got alignment issues i fix them with scene builder, where i create the static components by hand , which will be rendered allright , and inside them  i place the dynamic components. So your pane could be made from scene builder starting with a basic anchor pane and inside it place 3 panes with your default width, and inside them  dynamically add the images you wish each time.
hope it helps...

Comment: my problem is that, when I click on the Rectangle, it changes it's height and width but it shifts outside its container.

Comment: there are 2 things in your code i dont like . 1. the whole image is 500x450 while you are asking for 100x100x3 to fit , so are the panes place properly in your fxml ? 2. the rotate method i am not quite sure if you are using it right check this he notices a pivot point http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/transformations/rotation.htm

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I just solved it, trying with rotation pivots even if I'm not sure I have understood it well, yet. I'll post the code if it will work.